# Sphinx search / Filter provides different results then same query against database

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

In my config file ..

```
sql_query = select pr.id, pr.sf_skus, pr.name, pr.description, pr.sf_vendors,
            pr.sf_product_kw, \
            pr.sf_family_kw, pr.sf_class_kw, pr.sf_group_kw, pr.sf_category_kw, \
            pr.sf_sku_descriptions, \
            pc.item_category_id, pc.item_group_id, pc.item_class_id, \
            pc.item_family_id \
            from products as pr \
            left join product_cats as pc on pc.product_id = pr.id

sql_attr_uint = item_category_id
sql_attr_uint = item_group_id
sql_attr_uint = item_class_id
sql_attr_uint = item_family_id
```

when i run ....

```
search --filter item_family_id 12
```

I get a total of 26 documents found.

on the database when i run (the exact same query (i think))...

```
select pr.id, pr.sf_skus, pr.name, pr.description, pr.sf_vendors, pr.sf_product_kw,
pr.sf_family_kw, pr.sf_class_kw, pr.sf_group_kw, pr.sf_category_kw,
pr.sf_sku_descriptions,
pc.item_category_id, pc.item_group_id, pc.item_class_id,
pc.item_family_id
from products as pr
join product_cats as pc on pc.product_id = pr.id

where pc.item_family_id = 12
```

I get 41 results.

Shouldn't these two be identical? What am i doing wrong. TIA

Comment: Try running the query via the sphinxapi or sphinxql. DO NOT use the 'search' tool, its unmaintained and very broken. Its been removed from latest version of sphinx, because it was forgot about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you use different joins (LEFT JOIN in first query and JOIN in second). Second, you can run `mysql` client and watch to your index content using:

```
SELECT * FROM your_index LIMIT 100;
```

It can be that your query to `sphinx` returns only part of results.

Comment: Typo in the actual setup they are both left join and yes i made sure it wasn't a limit or an issue with the number of returned results. Also i am using postgres not mysql not sure if that matters.

Comment: Yes, I know that you use postgres. I mean that sphinxsearch has an sql client(like `psql` for postgres) which you can run using `mysql`. You can find an example [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/sphinxql.html).